question about some algebraic simplifications performed as we solve differential equations with Laplace transform
I am trying to follow this discussion of Laplace transforms on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofvkZXgbIxE&t=610s
The relevant portion is 10 minutes in to the video.
There is some algebra that I did not completely follow. Can someone
help me understand why the last step is valid?  Maybe we can break it
into more steps, or describe the underlying technique used?  Thanks !
UPDATE:  Seems like the last step was done by partial fraction decomposition. But I'm not seeing it ;^(
$$
-y(0) + (s+1) \int_{0}^\infty y e^{-st} \, dt = \frac{4}{s-3}
$$
$$
(s+1) \int_{0}^\infty y e^{-st} \, dt = y(0) + \frac{4}{s-3}
$$
$$
\int_{0}^\infty y e^{-st} \, dt = \frac{y(0)}{s+1} + \frac{4}{(s-3)(s+1)}
$$
$$
\int_{0}^\infty y e^{-st} \, dt = \frac{y(0) - 1}{s+1} + \frac{1}{s-3}.
$$

there is a typo: the numerator 4 in the last equation should be 1, because $\frac{1}{s-3}-\frac{1}{s+1}=\frac{4}{(s-3)(s+1)}$.
